# What's the popular repositories algorithm in GitHub

Tags: git, github

The screenshot below is from my personal page, https://github.com/litaotao

It shows that my popular repositories is as:

- guidetodatamining
- ipython-notebook-spark
- **IPython-Dashboard**
- The-Art-Of-Programming-By-July
- ipydb

I feel confused, for in the past long time the order was not like this, the repo **IPython-Dashboard** was in order 5, is something like this,

- guidetodatamining
- ipython-notebook-spark
- ipydb
- The-Art-Of-Programming-By-July
- **IPython-Dashboard**

but these is no either `stars`, `watch` or `forks` for this repo in the last day, what happened to promote the repo from fifth to third.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

maybe calculated by coefficients * [views, stars, forks, watches ...] not just only use [stars, forks, watches]

Answer (score 0):

I sent an email to the github support team, and got a reply like bellow:

`Thanks for the question, but we don't share that publicly.`

ok, that's fine.